# Function Composition: $ versus `.`

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel, comparative-review

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#loading-modules) offers the `findKey` function:

Here's the book's implementation:

```
findKey :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> v  
findKey key xs = snd . head . filter (\(k,v) -> key == k) $ xs
```

I implemented it with `$`:

```
findKey' :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> v  
findKey' k xs = snd $ head $ filter ((== k) . fst) xs
```

As far as I can tell, it's a stylistic choice here to select `.` over `$`?

Lastly, is there a way to write `findKey` such that the `[(k,v)]` is curried & thus not required in the signature of `findKey key xs`?

Answer (score 3):

Both are fine, and it's a matter of choice.

The first definition, being a composition of functions, treats `snd . head . filter (\(k, v) -> key == k)` as one big function.  It can therefore be transformed more easily into point-free style, if you like that kind of thing.

```
findKey'' :: (Eq k) => k -> ([(k, v)] -> v)
findKey'' key = snd . head . filter (\(k,v) -> key == k)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a stylistic choice, yes.

> is there a way to write `findKey` such that the `[(k,v)]` is curried & thus not required in the signature of `findKey key xs`?

If you mean a way to avoid having pairs in the type: no, if the function operates on a list of pairs, pairs must appear in its type.

If you mean a way to filter with a curried function instead of one taking a tuple, `uncurry` is the closest approximation:

```
filter (uncurry \k v -> k == key) xs
```

Note that the Prelude supplies a predefined function much like `findKey`:

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b.
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you were working with functions it turns out to be identical. But the $ operator is a generalization of the . operator, I mean, the dot operator (.) must be implemented with functions, but the dollar operator ($) is universal. The $ operator is implemented to avoid using parenthesis. A very simple and elegant rule to memorize its functionality

```
sum :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> a
sum a b = (a + b)
```

versus

```
sum2 :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> a
sum2 a b = $ a + b
```